# ElasticSearch: prevent lowercase indexing

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, nosql

I am re-indexing `Firebase` data to `ElasticSearch` for multi-location queries.

But when I save `id` auto generated by `ref.child('Users').push()` for example: `-KrjGdtUqG8LkTvTZKXO` is indexed as a lowercase string(`krjgdtuqg8lktvtzkxo`).
So when I sort the users by its id in ElassticSearch, the orders are different from Firebase.

How can I properly index `id` to keep the orders with Firebase?

Comment: Do you want to index your the id from firebase as the id of the elasticsearch document or as a value of a field in your elasticsearch document?

Comment: I want to index it as a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you are using elasticsearch without defining an analyser for your field, elasticsearch will by default use the standard analyser. The standard analyser will lowercase your content.

To solve your issue you should define a custom analyser or use an analyser that doesn't lowercase the content at the indexation time.

I will show you how to use another analyser than the standard one:

```
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "yourIndex":{  
         "properties":{  
            "theFieldWithYourID":{  
               "analyzer":"whitespace"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here in your mapping you define another analyser for the field you want. The white space analyser doesn't lowercase the content: [White space analyser documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html)

**EDIT:**
A more clean way to do what you want is to specify in your mapping that you are using a keyword and that it shouldn't be indexed:

```
PUT yourIndex/_mapping/yourDocType
{  
  "properties":{  
      "YourFireBaseID":{  
        "type":"keyword",
        "index":"not_analyzed"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The power of elasticsearch :) if you want to understand better Analyser I made that tutorial: https://github.com/melvynator/elasticsearch_presentation

Comment: I just though of your problem again I updated my answer for a cleaner way.